# UITableView cells in side menu disappear

Tags: ios, tableview

I am having some odd behavior in a side menu. Here is what it should look like:

[image]

After I click the button to the right of Organization I use this code to show some more cells

```
[self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

If I navigate from the menu with the organization cells showing and then navigate back to the menu it shows this:

[image]

The cells show as hidden, but when I set the cells to not hidden like this:
        cell.hidden = NO;
it still shows as hidden.

Any ideas as to what is going on? There is nowhere in my code that I set any cells as hidden.

If there is more code you need, then let me know.

Thanks

Here is some more code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"MenuCell";
MenuTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[MenuTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}

if (indexPath.section == 0)
{
    if (showOrgs && indexPath.row < organizations.count)
    {
        cell.label.text = [organizations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.leftImageView.hidden = YES;
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithHex:@"#ff6b01" alpha:1.0];
        cell.tag = 10002;
        cell.leftButton.hidden = YES;
        cell.righttButton.hidden = YES;
        cell.leftButton.enabled = NO;
        cell.righttButton.enabled = NO;
    }
    else if (showOrgs && indexPath.row >= organizations.count)
    {
        if (indexPath.row == organizations.count)
        {
            cell.label.text = [allUpper objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];//[organizations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            cell.label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            cell.tag = 10001;
            [cell.leftImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"dashboard"]];
            cell.leftImageView.hidden = NO;
        }
        else
        {
            cell.label.text = [allUpper objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            cell.label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            cell.tag = 10003;
            if ([[allUpper objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"All Media"])
            {
                cell.leftImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image-btn"];
                cell.leftImageView.hidden = NO;
            }
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"Row: %li", (long)indexPath.row);
    if (!showOrgs && [[upperSection objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"Dashboard"])
    {
        cell.label.text = [upperSection objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];//[organizations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.tag = 10001;
        cell.hidden = NO;
        [cell.leftImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"dashboard"]];
    }
    else if (!showOrgs && [[upperSection objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"All Media"])
    {
        cell.label.text = [upperSection objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.tag = 10003;
        cell.hidden = NO;
        if ([[upperSection objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"All Media"])
        {
            cell.leftImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image-btn"];
        }
    }
}

//    if (indexPath.section == 0 && showOrgs)
//        cell.label.text = [organizations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
else if (indexPath.section == 1)
    cell.label.text = [currentEvents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
else
    cell.label.text = [allEvents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
if (section == 0 && !showOrgs)
    return upperSection.count;
else if (section == 0 && showOrgs)
    return allUpper.count;
else if (section == 1)
    return currentEvents.count;
else
    return allEvents.count;
}
```

Comment: Could you add some code to make it easier to follow? What cells are added when the `Organization` button is pressed? What is triggering the menu to get back to the "normal" way?

Comment: @RaphaelSilva I added the cellForRowAtIndex method. I just have some hardcoded items in an array to add on top of the list. When the menu is closed the BOOL showOrgs is set to no, and then I reload the tableview

Comment: Can you show your `numberOfRowsInSection` method?

Comment: Also, if you put breakpoints, are you hitting the right blocks of code for when `showOrgs` is true?  And if I could make a suggestion for readability of your code,  I would split your cell logic into one conditional block for showOrgs = YES vs showOrgs = NO, so you don't have to include it in all of your conditionals.

Comment: @wottle Thanks for the suggestion, I will clean it up. I have used breakpoints. It is for sure entering the correct blocks

Comment: Are you returning the correct rowHeight for the cells?

Comment: Yes, I only return one row height, which is 40

Comment: cell.leftButton.hidden = NO;
cell.righttButton.hidden = NO;
cell.leftImageView.hidden = NO;
do it after the cell creation.after if(cell == nil) block

Comment: @MuhammadZohaibEhsan isn't it already after the if(cell == nil) block?

Comment: its in if conditions. i am saying soon after the block :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some changes to the blocks following the suggestion of wottle and then added this to the end of the block for when not showing orgs

```
cell.leftButton.hidden = NO;
cell.righttButton.hidden = NO;
cell.leftButton.enabled = YES;
cell.righttButton.enabled = YES;
cell.leftImageView.hidden = NO;
cell.label.hidden = NO;
cell.label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

That seems to have solved it. Thanks for all your help.